# Factorize symbolic expression in quadratic form

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Suppose I have in Matlab a symbolic equation like this

```
syms x y z real

T = 2*x^2 + k*y^2 + 6*k*x*y
```

How can I find the matrix B such that

```
T = [x y] * B * [x y]'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In Matlab2013a there is the hessian function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've just resolved this problem by myself.

```
B = 0.5 * jacobian(jacobian(T,V),V)
```

where `V` is a vector of variables.

The explanation it's a bit mathematical. If you want more details just ask to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem here. If you know the coefficients, can't you just extract them from the equation and create B from that?

I.e.:

```
[x y ] * [ a b ; c d ] * [ x y ]' = ax^2 + dy^2 + (b + c)xy = ax^2 + dy^2 + exy
```

So

```
B = [ a 0 ; b e ]
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to extract *automatically* this coefficient from the original equation.

Comment: Can you give the code you use to create an equation? (I've never worked with them, so I wouldn't know how to create an "equation" object.)

Comment: It's a very complicated formula. :( It's the kinetic energy of a 3R robot manipulator. However I add to my question more details about symbolic formula in matlab.

Comment: Ah, but I don't need to get your exact formula. Can you just give me some MATLAB code that creates an object of the same type as your equation? Then I can play around with it and see if I can extract the coefficients.